# MDPI does not support urdu, polyglossia is overwriting my title and not working with mdpi

Tags: polyglossia, mdpi, multilingual

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,XeLaTeX,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Package added for urdu writing/////
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainlanguage{english} % the document is in English

\setotherlanguage{urdu}   % with some bits in Urdu
 % the following line specifies Urdu font and its location
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Scale=1.25]{jameel.ttf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% eND OF Package added for urdu writing/////


%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands - do not modify
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2023}
\copyrightyear{2023}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname}

\datereceived{ } 
\daterevised{ } % Comment out if no revised date
\dateaccepted{ } 
\datepublished{ } 
\datecorrected{} % For corrected papers: "Corrected: XXX" date in the original paper.
\dateretracted{} % For corrected papers: "Retracted: XXX" date in the original paper.
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
%\doinum{}
%\pdfoutput=1 % Uncommented for upload to arXiv.org


%=================================================================
% Add packages and commands here. The following packages are loaded in our class file: fontenc, inputenc, calc, indentfirst, fancyhdr, graphicx, epstopdf, lastpage, ifthen, float, amsmath, amssymb, lineno, setspace, enumitem, mathpazo, booktabs, titlesec, etoolbox, tabto, xcolor, colortbl, soul, multirow, microtype, tikz, totcount, changepage, attrib, upgreek, array, tabularx, pbox, ragged2e, tocloft, marginnote, marginfix, enotez, amsthm, natbib, hyperref, cleveref, scrextend, url, geometry, newfloat, caption, draftwatermark, seqsplit
% cleveref: load \crefname definitions after \begin{document}

%=================================================================
% Please use the following mathematics environments: Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, Proposition, Characterization, Property, Problem, Example, ExamplesandDefinitions, Hypothesis, Remark, Definition, Notation, Assumption
%% For proofs, please use the proof environment (the amsthm package is loaded by the MDPI class).

%=================================================================
% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
\Title{This is My Title Page which is not working with polyglossia package}
% it works if Title is replaced with \tile , but then the formate of mdpi is no longer supported
% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{TS $^{1,\dagger}$\orcidA{}, Hs $^{2,\ddagger}$, SS $^{2,\ddagger}$ and WE $^{2,}$*}
%Author is also working if i chnge the Author to authors
%\longauthorlist{yes}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
$^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3.} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
% The commands \thirdnote{} till \eighthnote{} are available for further notes

%\simplesumm{} % Simple summary



% Abstract (Do not insert blank lines, i.e. \\) 
\abstract{
}

% Keywords
\keyword{Tw; PU.)} 



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Introduction}
this is introduction 
\texturdu { احتجاج، , ریلی وغیرہ}.

\section{Methodology}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Results}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am using mdpi template, I need to write the urdu text, so i added pacakge polyglossia in my code. it worked for writing urdu text but the title of my template is missing when I run the code, i tried many other ways along with urdu babel package but template tile page is not working. I need a way that i would be able to write the urdu in mdpi template without changing in the template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can always edit your question (via the "Edit" link below it) and add information to it directly. This might be better that adding comments. Also, maybe provide a link where to find the used document class. Did you get it from [www.mdpi.com/authors/latex](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)?

Comment: WRT `babel`, if all you need are “some bits in Urdu“, the following setup seems to work: `\usepackage[bidi=default,english]{babel}` `\babelfont[urdu]{rm}{jameel.ttf}` `\newcommand\texturdu[1]{\foreignlanguage{urdu}{#1}}`

Comment: @JavierBezos, it worked, thanks a lot